# Visualforce Email Template Help

Tags: visualforce, email-template

So I am working on a Visualforce Email Template and I am stuck. I am trying to pull a field from a related object to the one that the template would be generated from. When I put in the Child Relationship Name into the code it says that it is not a valid field. I know this is the proper name and I know I have done this before. Not sure what I am missing here.

Error: Invalid field LineItems for SObject SBQQ__Quote__c

[image: Code]

Here is the Relationship field screenshot:
[image: Relationship Field Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use correct relationship API instead of `LineItems` if I can consider `relatedToType` is Custom Quote object and `LineItem` is also custom object.

I am guessing it could be `LineItems__r`

```
<apex:repeat var="li" value="{!relatedTo.LineItems__r}">

</apex:repeat>
```

**Update**

It will be better to use correct relationship API verifying from Workbench. Here is a sample picture.

[image: relationship]

Comment: It is actually a custom Quote object `SBQQ_Quote__c` and a custom Quote Line object `SBQQ__QuoteLine__c`. I will add a picture of the relationship field to my original post.

Comment: I tried that as well and I still get the same error.

Comment: Still same error.

Comment: verify your relationship API in workbench, see my updated answer

Comment: Genius Santanu. I always forget to check that. The relationship was actually `SBQQ__LineItems__r`